# Java error: "Can't open input server /Library/InputManagers/Inquisitor"

Tags: java, macos, osx-yosemite, netbeans-8

I'm just now getting into GUI's in Java and when experimenting with `JFrame` I get the following error:

```
java[3126:71534] Can't open input server /Library/InputManagers/Inquisitor
```

Despite the error the program runs fine, but I'd like to know what this is about as I couldn't find much about Inquisitor anywhere.

Running Netbeans 8.0.2 and Java 8 Update 40 on OS X Yosemite (10.10.2). The java code being run is:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Ikkuna extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

     JTextField syöte;
     JLabel vastaus;
     JButton painike;     

     public void setTitle(String string){
     super.setTitle(string);
     }

     public Ikkuna(){

     setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
     setTitle("Celsius / Fahrenheit -muunnos");
     this.setSize(400, 200); 
     this.setResizable(false); 

     JPanel paneeli = (JPanel) getContentPane();
     syöte = new JTextField(10); 
     vastaus = new JLabel("tuntematon"); 
     painike = new JButton("Laske");
     painike.addActionListener(this);
     syöte.addActionListener(this);
     paneeli.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 10,10));
     paneeli.add(syöte);
     paneeli.add(vastaus);
     paneeli.add(painike);
     setVisible(true);

}

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
     vastaus.setText("" + ((Integer.parseInt(syöte.getText())*1.8+32)));  

}

public static void main(String[] args){
Ikkuna i = new Ikkuna();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Don't worry about it, it has nothing to do with your code, although you're probably better of removing Inquisitor extension as there's a good chance that it's not working properly.

InputManagers are intended to be Keyboard/Mouse extensions for applications. The idea is that the code is loaded into applications and can change their behavior in relation to Mouse/Keyboard input, but are generally used as a mechanism for extending applications. They became more restricted in 10.5, where they had to be in the system supported location only (`/Library/InputManagers`), and stopped being loaded entirely on 64bit mode.

Java 8 is a 64bit only application, so if you're seeing this error, then it's probably because the extension is not being loaded because it's a 64bit application and the system doesn't load extensions in this case.

The extension `Inquisitor` doesn't look to have been updated in a long time, and was used to extend the functionality of Safari, adding auto-complete to the search bar. The default search functionality of Safari now includes auto-complete, so I would consider it obsoleted.

If you want extended functionality for Safari, there are other plugins which extend the behaviour, such as `Glims` (I used to use it, but stopped because I felt it destabilized safari more than usual).

Opening the `/Library/InputManagers` folder (open a Finder window, hit Command-G to get a location field and type in the directory, then hit enter) will allow you to see what input managers are present on the system.